# Prove a bounded harmonic function $u$ on $0<|z|<1$ has removable singularity at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

This is Exercise no.1, page 166 in *Complex Analysis* by Ahlfors.

> Prove that a bounded harmonic function $u$ on $0<|z|<1,$ has removable singularity at the origin?

I need a solution without using Poisson integral.

By the mean value property and boundedness of $u$, we get 
$\int_{|z|=r}ud\theta\ $ is a constant, say $\beta$.

What remains is to show that $u(z)\rightarrow \beta$ as $z\rightarrow 0.$

I am struggling at this point. How to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how you got the integrals of $u$ constant.

Comment: This integral will be a linear function of $log(r)$. By boundedness of $u$, the log part becomes absent.